# Get Power Supply Unit Information - C#

Tags: c#

Is there any way getting Power Supply Unit Information such as Model name, serial and Power in DC etc in C#?

I just find this link, Test and got nothing!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387973(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be, is there any way to get that information in software *at all*? (I strongly suspect not)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is unavailable to the OS. (How would the motherboard know? There aren't any data connections from the PSU.)

Comment: so what is the "CIM_PowerSupply class" ???

Comment: Just because a class was created does not mean that it currently works, or that it ever worked with a given hardware setup

Comment: Some server-class PSUs have a data connection to the motherboard.

Comment: Why downvote as long as msdn released such class :(

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Yes you can, but you need hardware capable of supplying the data.

--

Obtaining data from the power supply requires a PSU with PMBus (Power Mangement Bus) and a motherboard with the associated circuitry.

From [Wikipedia: Power Management Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Management_Bus):-

> The PMBus command space can be seen as exposing a variety of readable, and often writable, device attributes such as measured voltage and current levels, temperatures, fan speeds, and more. Different devices will expose different attributes.

There are several manufacturers of such PSUs, here I [quote from SuperMicro](https://www.supermicro.nl/products/nfo/power_supply.cfm) because I know they supply them:

> Supermicro's wide range of high efficiency power supplies offer many important features including [...] **remote monitoring with PMBus**

Note that it is possible to destroy the computer by setting PSU values outside what the other hardware in the computer is rated for.

Answer (score 0):

You should have access from some of the information you are looking for withing the CIM_PowerSupply class through a WMI query.

```
string NamespacePath = "\\\\.\\ROOT\\CIMV2\\power";
string ClassName = "CIM_PowerSupply";

ManagementClass oClass = new ManagementClass(NamespacePath + ":" + ClassName);

foreach (ManagementObject oObject in oClass.GetInstances())
{
    //access a property of the Management object
    oObject["ActiveInputVoltage"];
}
```

After you have the query collection you can access some of the properties found in the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387973(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: On that documentation page you're referencing, it says, "WMI does not implement this class". I wonder if any platform ever actually supported this?

Comment: Are you returning anything withing oObject?